# Struggling to implement jQuery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a jQuery script here: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm

I have entered the following (where fbrp__35 is the id of my input) after my form:

```
<script>
    $('#fbrp__35').pickadate()
</script>
```

But it's not working. I have also tried the following:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#fbrp__35').pickadate()
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second code should work. Have you include library files? Do you get any error in browser console?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: haver you open the dev tools in the chrom browser? are there some errors?

Comment: I've looked at in firebug and can't see any errors. I'll have a look in Chrome.

Comment: two errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: Picker is not defined and Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: There you go. You have not added library. Download from http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/v2-(deprecated)/index.htm

Comment: I've loaded legacy.js, picker.date.js, picker.js and picker.time.js in the head.

Comment: It seems they were loaded in the wrong order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library files need to be loaded in the following order:

```
legacy.js
picker.js
picker.date.js
picker.time.js
```

Comment: He is right! I had faced the same issue and followed the mentioned order and it worked!